# Enrich a dataset of POIs with OpenStreetMap

Tags: data, open-source-gis, point-of-interest, reverse-geocoding

I have a list of POIs, some with a full description and some with only a few data entries, like the following:

```
6.9441000   50.9242000  [50677] (Ital) Casa di Biase [Köln]
6.9373600   50.9291800  [50674] (Ital) Al Setaccio [Köln]
```

However, I need the full dataset. Can I get this somewhere? If I have all the position data, is it possible to find the rest?

- a. name of the street
- b. name of the town

So for example, the data should finally look like this:

```
10.5346100  52.1613600  [38300] (Chin) Wanbao Kommissstr.9 [Wolfenbüttel]
13.2832500  52.4422600  [14167] (Ital) LaPergola  Unter den Eichen 84d [Berlin]
13.3177700  52.5062900  [10625] (Chin) Good Friends  Kantstr.30 [Berlin]
```

Can I do this with OpenStreetMap? Should I parse OpenStreetMap data? Or OpenBabel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it personally (as I would use a [Bing Maps REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx) for that), but [gisgraphy](http://code.google.com/p/gisgraphy) sounds like it might be what you're looking for because it would provide you with an API to make searches using both [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org) and [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org) datasets.

> Gisgraphy is a free, open source framework that offers the possibility
>   to do geolocalisation and geocoding via Java APIs or REST webservices.
>   Because geocoding is nothing without data, it provides an easy to use
>   importer that will automagically download and import the necessary
>   (free) data to your local database (Geonames and OpenStreetMap : 42
>   million entries). You can also add your own data with the Web
>   interface or the importer connectors provided. Gisgraphy is production
>   ready, and has been designed to be scalable(load balanced), performant
>   and used in other languages than just java : results can be output in
>   XML, JSON, PHP, Python, Ruby, YAML, GeoRSS, and Atom. One of the most
>   popular GPS tracking System (OpenGTS) also includes a Gisgraphy
>   client...read more .

Source: http://code.google.com/p/gisgraphy/